# Odoo Keyerror in accounts list

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

**Description**

In odoo accounting module,there are 26 accounts each assigned with unique codes.Some are used for invoice(like creditors for invoice) and some for other purpose.We can see it in accounting module->configuration->Accounts->Accounts.I have imported many user defined accounts from my client's database.No error during import,all the account entries shows in my user interface.

**Error**

But when I open any of those entries,I am getting error like this

```
"Keyerror:261"
```

where 261 is the id of one of the account name.It exists both in the UI and DB.I know keyerror means it is a dictionary and it cant find a key called 261.Since id 261 is there in the DB why it is not able to search it?

Comment: on which model did you import the accounts? res.users?
please provide the entire error.

Comment: I imported it to account.account table